# Binomial theorem for $(1-x^2)^{n-\frac12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

According to the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), it is possible to expand any nonnegative power of $x + y$ into a sum of the form
$$(x+y)^{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^{k}.
$$
Is it possible to write a formula like the previous one for $(1-x^2)^{n-\frac12}$? (Here $|x|<1$.)

Comment: Yeah, the generalized binomial series. Look in the Generalizations section of the Wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n-\frac{1}{2}}{k}(-1)^kx^{2k}\qquad\qquad |x|<1}
> \end{align*}
> If we prefer integral upper indices of the binomial coefficients we can also write
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^kx^{2k}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We obtain (1) by writing
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{n-\frac{1}{2}}{k}}&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdots\left(n-k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{2.1}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!2^k}(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots(2n-2k+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{k!2^k}\,\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n-2k-1)!!}\tag{2.2}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!2^k}\,\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}\,\frac{(2n-2k)!!}{(2n-2k)!}\tag{2.3}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!2^k}\,\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\,\frac{2^{n-k}(n-k)!}{(2n-2k)!}\tag{2.4}\\
&=\frac{1}{4^k}\,\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\,\frac{(n-k)!}{k!(2n-2k)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2n}{2k}\frac{(2k)!(n-k)!}{n!k!}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we use the definition $\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{1}{k!}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$.
- In (2.2) we use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* $(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots3\cdot 1$.
- In (2.3) we apply $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!$.
- In (2.4) we apply $(2n)!!=2^nn!$.